# SharePoint 2010 to 2013 SharePoint Migration issues

Tags: sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2013

I recently migrated custom WebPart template solution (wsp), which has custom list definition, from SP2010 to SP2013 using Visual Studio 2013.  Set the Assembly Version to 15 and compiled over .Net Framework 4.5.  The deploymnet was successful.  But there are 2 problems:
1. When I created site using the custom template that was just deployed, the page displays cluttered icons, attached screen shots.  Also when trying to add permission to the site, a whole bunch of colorful cluttered icons appear on the site's Permissions page.
2. The other issue is, some of the CSS, specifically the ms-WPxxxxxxxx  (like WPTitle, WPHeader etc) are being inherited, probably from corev4.css. That’s what View Source shows.  The custom CSS is defined in the main page (CustomDefault.aspx) with “!important” tag, but that didn’t seem to be of any use.

The same solution was working perfect on SP2010.

Suspect mostly (1) is related to (2), I may be wrong.

To resolve (1), as advised by SP folks from MSDN Community forum, I changed the default master page to Oslo.master ==> that cleared the cluttering icons, but CSS and Javascripts werent working.  So I had to revert.
I also tried changing the "../_layouts/.." to "../_layouts/15/..", that didnt make any difference.

MSDN Community Thread: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f9199e0c-972b-45b9-b8fb-772028bc22d9/cluttered-icons-in-sharepoint-2013-post-migration-from-sp2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious#74fb3648-9776-4f68-82ba-b212102a1492

Any help will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bEA2.png)

Comment: After a long battle, I could only narrow down the problem, solving it partially.  I registered Corev15.css (SP2013 default CSS) on the Custom WebPart page since we dont have a Master page, the cluttering of icons disappeared.  But not on all pages, the AllItems.aspx, the user permission page etc have them still.  From the developer tool, I could see that these pages are using Corev4.css (SP2010), the image and layout paths are ".../15/images/..".  Any idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long battle, I finally fixed this problem.  Found that the 'onet.xml' in the SiteDefinition module was referring to SharePoint 2010 master page, v4.master.  Since this was another project, I did not have a clue that this file will have references to SP2010 resources.  Many blogs suggested only to change the resources path like '/_layouts/' to '/_layouts/15/' and the '/ControlTemplate/' to '/ControlTemplate/15/' but not seen anyone mentioning about master page change.  Probably may not be the case for a completely out-of-box solution.   So search for 'v4.master' (SP2010), in the project solution, if found, change it to your custom master page, if you have one, or to the default master page.  But if you have used any other master page or a custom master page that was exclusively meant for SP2010 or an older version of SharePoint, you would have to choose an equivalent one or customize it to make it compatible with SP2013.

So here's the code snippet that was changed and that got rid of the cluttering icons, hope it helps someone out there.

```
<!-- <Configuration ID="-1" Name="NewWeb" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/**v4.master**" />
     <Configuration ID="0" Name="Default" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/**v4.master**"> 
     <Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/**v4.master**">
     <Configuration ID="2" Name="DWS" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/**v4.master**"> -->

     <Configuration ID="1" Name="NewWeb" MasterUrl="~masterurl/**default.master**" />
     <Configuration ID="0" Name="Default" MasterUrl="~masterurl/*default.master*">
     <Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank" MasterUrl="~masterurl/**default.master**">
     <Configuration ID="2" Name="DWS" MasterUrl="~masterurl/**default.master**">
```